# print a table of feet/centimeter equivalences in python

Tags: for-loop, while-loop, range

Using for loop and while loop, print a table of feet/centimeter equivalences. Let f
be the
height in feet ranging from 5 to 6ft in the step of 0.1ft. For each value off, print the
corresponding height in centimeter.

Comment: You might have forgotten to ask a question.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.